# MVC Default Connection

Tags: c#, security, model-view-controller

I'm trying to change the default database context to use my actual database, and also to possibly use my User table instead of the default one generated by MVC. I've seen multiple things stating what all the parts are, and what they do (and a million and one theories on what it should do), but I've not seen a concrete code example of how to actually do this. I don't feel what I want to do is that complicated, but I can't find a straight forward answer to actually show me how to just change the defaultconnection to use my database and my tables.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: " generated by MVC" - there is no "MVC" in .Net Framework or C#. There is MVVM implemetation in WPF and ASP.Net-MVC... But neither generates tables. Some clarification on what you actually used could make question better.

Comment: I think he means the MVC template in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question at one point, and am still a little confused about the implementation. Basically, it sounds like you're trying to get the authentication pieces generated by the MVC template to connect to a database other than localhost default?

Check in your Web.config and you should see the "DefaultConnection":

```html
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\{blahblahblah}.mdf;Initial Catalog={}blahblahblah};Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I think if you update this connection string you'll get what you're looking for. Let me know if that's not what you mean.